# Save Upload image into local system folder in jsf 2.0

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am new to jsf frame work.I am using jsf2.0 in eclipse ide.I have try to upload a images in jsf2.0.I have uploaded the image but it stored on eclipse server.The problem is when i clean the server the images are deleted.So i need a help,to upload photo into system local folder.please find and help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify an **absolute** path in `new File` (or `new FileOutputStream`, depending on how you're locating the result file).

So, do not do

```
File file = new File("uploads/filename.ext");
```

but rather do

```
File file = new File("/uploads/filename.ext");
```

*(note the starting `/`)*

This way it will be stored on exactly that location in the disk file system instead of relative to the directory from where the JVM is been started.

Comment: Sorry, I can't do anything with this information. You need to tell more about the problem. I am unable to beam over to you in person to look at the problem with my own eyes.