# System cannot find the file specify in jsf2.0

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have using jsf2.0 in eclipse ide.I have a problem to store a image in local folder.The images are stored in local folder with 0 bytes.The images are read and write into 0 bytes.

Backing Bean:

public class uploadImageAction {

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) throws IOException {


    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    PhotoBean photoBean = (PhotoBean) context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{photoBean}", PhotoBean.class);
    PhotoBean photoBean2 = (PhotoBean) context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{photoBean2}", PhotoBean.class);

    ExternalContext extContext=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();

    File file = new  File(extContext.getRealPath(event.getFile().getFileName()));


      System.out.println("Hibernate save image into database");
        Session session = HibernateUtil1.getSessionFactory().openSession();

        session.beginTransaction();

        //save image into database
        //File file = new File("D:\\1.gif");
        //byte[] bFile = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        //System.out.println("DDDDDDDDDDDD"+bFile);

        byte[] bfile = new byte[(int)file.length()];
        System.out.println("DDDDDDDDDDDD"+bfile);
        try {
             FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
             //convert file into array of bytes
             fileInputStream.read(bfile);
             fileInputStream.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Cannnoy");
             e.printStackTrace();
            }

        String urlImage = file.toString();

        String imageName = event.getFile().getFileName();


        photoBean.setPathName(file);

        //file = photoBean.getPathName();

        photoBean.setImageName(imageName);

        imageName = photoBean.getImageName();

        photoBean.setUrl(urlImage);

        urlImage = photoBean.getUrl();


    //  PhotoDaoService photoDaoService = new PhotoDaoService();

        System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++++++++"+file);


 System.out.println("CHECK BYTES"+bfile);
     //   uploadImageBean upldImageBean = new uploadImageBean();
        //upldImageBean.setImageByte(bfile);
        photoBean.setByteImage(bfile);
        //avatar.setImage(bFile);
       // System.out.println("dfdffdf"+upldImageBean.setImageByte(bFile));


        session.save(photoBean);


        //Get image from database
         photoBean2 = (PhotoBean)session.get(PhotoBean.class, photoBean.getId());
        byte[] bImage = photoBean2.getByteImage();
        System.out.println("QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ"+bImage);
        int i=0;
        try{
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("e:/out/out"+0+".jpg"); 
            fos.write(bImage);
            fos.close();
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Succesful", event.getFile().getFileName()
                    + " is uploaded.");

                    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("UPLOAD DISPLAY EXCEPTION");
        }

        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }

}
```

The Error Occurs:

```
Hibernate save image into database
bytes[B@12fb7ef
java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\Mecherie_project\.metadata\.plugins \org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\image_web\baby.jpg (The system cannot find  the file specified)

at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
at image.uploadImageAction.handleFileUpload(uploadImageAction.java:45)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:234)
```

Comment: _"The images are stored in local folder with 0 bytes.The images are read and write into 0 bytes."_ What does that mean?

Comment: @Matt: OP is somehow expecting that an uploaded file is magically present by the `File` as represented by `new  File(extContext.getRealPath(event.getFile().getFileName()));`. The OP is attempting to read it using `FileInputStream` which obviously won't work because the file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As answered so [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019917/save-upload-image-into-local-system-folder-in-jsf-2-0) [times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037689/jsf-image-upload-in-folder) [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020156/upload-into-system-folder-using-jsf2-0), you should **not** store/locate uploaded files in public web content. You should be using an absolute path instead. E.g.

```
File file = new File("/path/to/images", filename);
// ...
```

The uploaded file is not magically present in the expanded WAR, so reading it with `FileInputStream` won't work at all. You'd have to read it from `event.getFile().getInputStream()` and then write it to an arbitrary `OutputStream` such as `FileOutputStream`.

But now your *real* problem is more clear than in your previous questions. You seem to want to save the uploaded file in the database. There's then *no need* to store the file on local disk file system first. Just stream the received bytes to a `byte[]` directly and the save it in the DB.

```
InputStream input = event.getFile().getInputstream();
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

for (int length; (length = input.read(buffer)) > -1;) {
    output.write(buffer, 0, length);
}

photoBean.setByteImage(output.toByteArray());
```

Comment: BalusC thanks for ur responses, clearly what i need is, whenever i upload a image it must get saved in any folder in the server, may be "\images" or something, and the link of the saved image must be saved in the DB, i have no problem with DB now.the Link properly saved in my table. but the real problem is while retrieving the image with the help of that link, my image file saved there as 0 bytes file and and it is displayed like an cross mark.

Comment: That was because you weren't reading the uploaded image by `event.getFile().getInputStream()`. You have just created a non-existing file and then attempted to read from it.